# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que palabras en divs queden una enfrente de la otra como un párrafo normal?

Tags: html, css

Tengo la siguiente estructura html así:

```html
<div class="container-words">
  <div class="content">
    <label class="activity-1-words">Sherlock</label>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <label class="activity-1-words">Holmes,</label>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <label class="activity-1-words">que</label>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <label class="activity-1-words">en</label>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <label class="activity-1-words">un</label>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <label class="activity-1-words">principio</label>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <label class="activity-1-words">Doyle</label>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <label class="activity-1-words">tenía</label>
  </div>
```

Esta es la forma en que se ve

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y necesito que está quede de la siguiente manera, como un texto normal.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se si solo con estilos (aunque no creo), o si es necesario utilizar JS

Cabe mencionar que esa estructura html surge de una plantilla hecha con [twig](/questions/tagged/twig).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es necesario js. Con la regla *display* de CSS es suficiente:

```css
div {display:inline}
```

```html
<div class="container-words">
              <div class="content">
          <label class="activity-1-words">Sherlock</label>
        </div>
              <div class="content">
          <label class="activity-1-words">Holmes,</label>
        </div>
              <div class="content">
          <label class="activity-1-words">que</label>
        </div>
              <div class="content">
          <label class="activity-1-words">en</label>
        </div>
              <div class="content">
          <label class="activity-1-words">un</label>
        </div>
              <div class="content">
          <label class="activity-1-words">principio</label>
        </div>
              <div class="content">
          <label class="activity-1-words">Doyle</label>
        </div>
              <div class="content">
          <label class="activity-1-words">tenía</label>
</div>
```

Comment: De hecho con aplicarle la regla al div sea por un selector de tipo o por selector de clase alcanza, poner el label esta demás pues los [`labels`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elementos_en_l%C3%ADnea) son elementos en línea y lo que debemos modificar nadamás son los divs que contienen a estos

Comment: Muchas gracias @BetaM fue la solución mas rápida, así lo necesitaba.

Comment: @BetaM, tienes razón. Lo puse casi sin mirar. Gracias por el apunte.